# How can I combine nom parsers to get a more bit-oriented interface to the data?

Tags: rust, nom, ais

I'm working on decoding [AIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_identification_system) messages in Rust using [nom](http://rust.unhandledexpression.com/nom/).

AIS messages are made up of a bit vector; the various fields in each message are an arbitrary number of bits long, and they don't always align on byte boundaries.

This bit vector is then ASCII encoded, and embedded in an [NMEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_0183) sentence.

From http://catb.org/gpsd/AIVDM.html:

> The data payload is an ASCII-encoded bit vector. Each character represents six bits of data. To recover the six bits, subtract 48 from the ASCII character value; if the result is greater than 40 subtract 8. According to [IEC-PAS], the valid ASCII characters for this encoding begin with "0" (64) and end with "w" (87); however, the intermediate range "X" (88) to "_" (95) is not used.

### Example

- `!AIVDM,1,1,,A,D03Ovk1T1N>5N8ffqMhNfp0,0*68` is the NMEA sentence
- `D03Ovk1T1N>5N8ffqMhNfp0` is the encoded AIS data
- `010100000000000011011111111110110011000001100100000001011110001110000101011110001000101110101110111001011101110000011110101110111000000000` is the decoded AIS data as a bit vector

### Problems

I list these together because I think they may be related...

#### 1. Decoding ASCII to bit vector

I can do this manually, by iterating over the characters, subtracting the appropriate values, and building up a byte array by doing lots of work bitshifting, and so on. That's fine, but it seems like I should be able to do this inside nom, and chain it with the actual AIS bit parser, eliminating the interim byte array.

#### 2. Reading arbitrary number of bits

It's possible to read, say, 3 bits from a byte array in nom. But, each call to `bits!` seems to consume a full byte at once (if reading into a `u8`).

For example:

```
named!(take_3_bits<u8>, bits!(take_bits!(u8, 3)));
```

will read 3 bits into a `u8`. But if I run `take_3_bits` twice, I'll have consumed 16 bits of my stream.

I can combine reads:

```
named!(get_field_1_and_2<(u8, u8)>, bits!(pair!(take_bits!(u8, 2), take_bits!(u8, 3))));
```

Calling `get_field_1_and_2` will get me a `(u8, u8)` tuple, where the first item contains the first 2 bits, and the second item contains the next 3 bits, but nom will then still advance a full byte after that read.

I can use `peek` to prevent the nom's read pointer from advancing, and then manually manage it, but again, that seems like unnecessary extra work.

Comment: For part 2, it seems the problem isn't that big; I just need to write all of my parsers without being `bits!`-aware, then put the `bits!` in the very top level parser that I call. I'll write up more if I can figure out part 1. (Right now, I am manually building up that bit vector.)

Comment: Yes, I've done something similar, and the answer to 2 is that you need to separate your byte-oriented and bit-oriented parsing, and call `bits!` once, when you change mode.

Comment: @DanHulme thanks for that. I've started getting that part worked out. Was hoping for a big insight into part 1, but it's looking like it'll just be a 2-step process. I'll post an answer here with some code next chance I get.

Comment: Several years later, I don't have a great followup, but the code at least is available at https://github.com/squidpickles/ais/